# How to convert arrays inside a list into individual matrices within a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply

I have a list that contains 22 nested lists, I want to convert each of these nested lists into matrices with dimensions 640 x640.

I have tried running a loop that unlists each element and then converts each one into a matrix.

````
```
output=list()
for ( i in 1:22){
output[[i]] <- matrix(unlist(m1[[i]]), ncol = 640, byrow = TRUE)
}
````

I expected to get a list containing 22 matrices of 640x640. However, it just returned 22 nested lists again

Comment: I tried reproducing this with a simple list of lists of random numbers of length 4, what you did here should work. Could you elaborate on what actually goes wrong?

Comment: My output is just a list containing 22 lists within it, the elements within it should all be matrices of dimensions 640x 640

Comment: I created a simple example with `example <- list(rnorm(4), rnorm(4), rnorm(4))` and run the loop you provide in your question on that (with different numbers, of course) and it works perfectly. This leads me to believe the problem lies with the original list of lists. Could you show THAT list?